# Скрыть основное меню сайта на мобильном устройстве и планшете, MDL

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, material-design

Как сделать что бы когда пользователь заходил на сайт с мобильного устройства или планшета, основное меню nav скрывалось, а боковое меню drawer, поиск и вкладки tab оставались видимы?
Так же как сделать что бы первые 4 пункта 'a' в nav меню drawer были скрыты на компьютере, но видны на мобильном устройстве и планшете?
Используется фреймворк MDL.

```
<div class="content-grid">
<div class="mdl-layout
        mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header
        mdl-layout--fixed-tabs">
    <header class="mdl-layout__header">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
            <span class="mdl-layout-title">Leniva</span>
            <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>

            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable">
                <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" for="search-expandable">
                    <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                </label>
                <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
                    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="search-expandable" />
                    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="search-expandable">Search text</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Tabs -->
        <div class="mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect">
            <a href="#fixed-tab-1" class="mdl-layout__tab is-active">Kittens</a>
            <a href="#fixed-tab-2" class="mdl-layout__tab">Papies</a>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Leniva</span>
        <nav class="mdl-navigation">
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="bemmdl.html">Home</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="bemmdl2.html">Blog</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="bemmdl3.html">About</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="bemmdl4.html">Contact</a>
            <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Products</a>
            <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Services</a>
            <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Portfolios</a>
            <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Achievements</a>
            <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Blog</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Для отображения только на больших экранах необходимо добавить:

`mdl-layout--large-screen-only`

А только на мобильных:

`mdl-layout--small-screen-only`

Для вашего случая получится так:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-800 />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-A400ompatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <title>Google Material Design </title>
  <meta name="description" content="Google material design">
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-800' />

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.red-orange.min.css" />

  <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="https://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content-grid">
    <div class="mdl-layout
        mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header
        mdl-layout--fixed-tabs">
      <header class="mdl-layout__header">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
          <span class="mdl-layout-title">Leniva</span>
          <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>

          <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable">
            <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" for="search-expandable">
                    <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                </label>
            <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
              <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="search-expandable" />
              <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="search-expandable">Search text</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Tabs -->
        <div class="mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
          <a href="#fixed-tab-1" class="mdl-layout__tab is-active">Kittens</a>
          <a href="#fixed-tab-2" class="mdl-layout__tab">Papies</a>
        </div>
      </header>

      <div class="mdl-layout__drawer mdl-layout--small-screen-only">
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Leniva</span>
        <nav class="mdl-navigation">
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="bemmdl.html">Home</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="bemmdl2.html">Blog</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="bemmdl3.html">About</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="bemmdl4.html">Contact</a>
          <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Products</a>
          <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Services</a>
          <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Portfolios</a>
          <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Achievements</a>
          <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Blog</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: код принято оставлять в ответе. Внешние сервисы периодически падают, контент по ссылке изменяется или позже удаляется вовсе. Чтобы Быть увереным что Ваш ответ долго будет служить сообществу лучше перенести код в тело ответа. Кстати сниппеты для CSS/HTML/JavaScript в редакторе ответа также имеются

Comment: @МихаилРебров спасибо за совет, учту.

Answer (score 0):

@media запросы в помощь.

к примеру

скрыты на планшете и телефоне, размер пикселей можно изменять

```
@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
  .nav{
    display:none;
  }
  .mdl-navigation__link:nth-last-child(n+6){
    display:block;
  }
 }
```

скрыты на компьютере

```
@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .nav{
    display:block;
  }
  .mdl-navigation__link:nth-last-child(n+6){
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Есть ли какое-нибудь решение MDL, типа .mdl-cell—hide-desktop(tablet/phone) или mdl-layout--fixed-header? Из этого мне ничего не удалось успешно применить в этой ситуации)

Comment: Это решение не работает